# VS2010 MSI setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment

I haven't seen this problem when browsing the web, so here it is:

I used the .msi file (vs. right click -> Install, option on the setup project) to install "Version 1.0.7" product onto my computer.

I then changed my "Version" to 1.0.8 , and **all** projects Assembly Version/AssemblyFileVersion properties to 1.0.8.0.  I deleted the old Primary Output, and added a new one where I made sure the version was correct under the KeyOutput expanded list.  I did this because it didn't update after I changed all Assembly Versions to 1.0.8.0, and it stayed at 1.0.7.0 (the previous version).

I built my Setup project and went to my folder that contained the new 1.0.8 .msi file.  I double-clicked and got the "Application already exists, remove existing in Add/Remove Programs" (or similar) dialog, and it stopped installation.

So I checked my:
 **ProductCode**-they were the same between new/old versions,
 **UpgradeCode**-also the same,
 **RemovePreviousVersion** property-set to **True** between both versions.  This is what I checked because I usually found as a solution in all my other searches, but it wasn't working.

So I unistalled the 1.0.7 version, installed 1.0.8 and all worked fine.  Still didn't fix my problem where I shouldn't get the unistall first prompt.  Note: I've been installing on "Everyone".

I unistalled 1.0.8 again (at this point, no versions exist/are installed), and tried this:
1. Install 1.0.7 from .msi file **or** Install 1.0.7 by right clicking it's setup project and using the "Install" option.
2. Right clicked 1.0.8 setup project and used the Install option from there. 
3. No errors/dialogs pop up, the old version seems to have been unistalled first, then I continued with installation and new version was on the computer.  This is what I want!
As you can see here, I need to beable to use 1.0.7 .msi file to install, then when I need to patch/fix/update, I need to be able to 1.0.8 .msi to not display a "Already exists" prompt and just overwrite/merge, but this isn't happening unless I use VS2010 Right Click>Install on the Setup project.

Any help is appreciated.

edit added bolding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the ProductCode between the two versions. Read more on [major upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This did work I found out.  However, changing just the build number is considered a major upgrade?  I figured just make small changes would just be considered a patch...

Comment: I just did alot of testing, and you need to also update the Version number of the setup project...

Answer (score 0):

Installing a minor upgrade (which is the case when you change the ProductVersion but not ProductCode) requires specifying REINSTALL if and only if a previous version is present on the machine. There are ways to do this for explorer-launched scenarios by specifying it in the Property table and clearing it with a custom action, but it's much more common to handle it with a launcher or by using a major upgrade.